# How can I use emacs to allow comments within long gnuplot commands?

Tags: emacs, elisp, gnuplot, interactive

I have been using Gnuplot a lot lately, and I frequently come across
the following frustration: It is not possible to comment out a parts
of a multi-line plot command, if you do that you get a `function to
plot expected` error.  Here is an example*:

```
plot \
     "datafile1.dat" u 1:2 w lp,\
     # "datafile2.dat" u 1:2 w lp,\ <---- ERROR! cannot comment here
     "datafile3.dat" u 1:2 w lp,\
     "dummy" u 1:2
```

It's an annoying because I would like to plot many lines at once and
then comment some while I analyse the data, currently I need to delete
or move the lines I'm not interested in before I plot and then undo to
the original state before making a different comparison.  The problem,
as mentioned [here](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.graphics.apps.gnuplot/2009-08/msg00094.html), is that commenting out a continued line comments
out the entire command.

I am editing my script through emacs using `gnuplot-mode` and have
bound `C-c C-c` to `gnuplot-run-buffer` i.e.

```
(add-hook 'gnuplot-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
            (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-c") 'gnuplot-run-buffer)))
```

I guess it's possible to write a function that copies the script to a
temporary buffer but deleting comment lines (or perhaps just comment
lines in a long command) and then calls `gnuplot-run-buffer` on this
temporary buffer.  My elisp isn't great so it would take me a while to
figure out how to implement this well, I think this would be useful
though so I'm posting this question

* The last line is there so I don't have to remove the trailing
backslash of the last line.  The `dummy` file does not exist so it's
just ignored and not plotted.

Comment: You could also use several `replot` commands instead of `plot` with several lines: `plot x; replot x**2; replot x**3`.

Comment: You could cheat by adding `lw 0`, but this is still not a nice solution. I've never found a satisfying solution.

Comment: @Christoph Thanks, that's quite useful for quick work using the default terminal, unfortunately when I use the pdfcairo terminal for my final plot each replot command introduces a new page in the output pdf

Comment: Actually, it's not so inconvenient since it's easy to use the tool `pdftk` to correct the output. For example to get the last figure (the one with all the `replot` commands completed and appearing on the same figure) you can do this: `pdftk multipage.pdf cat end output singlepage.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

The following advice removes comment lines. It does not take care of the superfluous comma if you comment out the last plot line. But, you wrote that you do not mind that.

```
(defadvice gnuplot-send-string-to-gnuplot (before ignore-comments activate)
  "Ignore lines starting with #."
  (setq string (with-temp-buffer
         (insert string)
         (goto-char (point-min))
         (delete-matching-lines "^[[:blank:]]*#")
         (buffer-string))))
```